# Can't use ctrl z(Undo) after using the following code in excel 2019

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2019

I can't use ctrl z(Undo) after using the following code in excel 2019.

I want to merge 8 rows into a cell by using macros but I hope it can undo.

here is the code:

```
 
Sub main()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 8
            With .Cells(i, 1).Resize(8)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Cells(i, 2).Resize(8)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        With .Cells(i, 3).Resize(8)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        With .Cells(i, 4).Resize(8)
                .Merge
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excel VBA result cannot be undone. This is the way Excel behaves...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813806/is-it-possible-to-undo-a-macro-action

Comment: You can use [Application.OnUndo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onundo) to specify a Sub to run when Undo is called. You have to code the Undo actions yourself.  Note the regular Excel Undo stack is cleared whenever VBA takes an action that changes a something in Excel